# Krull Dimension of Direct Limits of Zero-Dimensional Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Is it true that direct limit of a directed system of zero-dimensional rings is zero-dimensional (in the sense of Krull)? Thanks for any help!

If this is true, it is inferred that any prime ideal of the direct limit must be maximal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P\subseteq Q$ are prime ideals in a ring $R=\varinjlim R_i$ with $\dim R_i=0$ for all $i$, then $P\cap R_i=Q\cap R_i$ for all $i$, so $P=Q$.

Comment: I know that if $N_i$ is the nilradical of $R_i$ then $\varinjlim N_i$ is the nilradical of $\varinjlim R_i$. Is it this fact which you used for getting the first equality (between the intersections) or something else? And by what rule could we pass direct limit through intersection to get $P=Q$? Thanks!

Comment: The equality between intersection follows since they are also prime ideals in $R_i$ with $P\cap R_i\subseteq Q\cap R_i$, and $\dim R_i=0$. We also have $R=\bigcup_iu_i(R_i)$ where $u_i:R_i\to R$ are the canonical morphisms. Then $P\cap R_i$ is in fact $u_i^{-1}(P)$, and similarly for $Q$. If $x\in Q$ then $x\in u_j(R_j)$ for some $j$, so $x=u_j(x_j)$. Then $x_j\in Q\cap R_j=P\cap R_j$, so $x=u_j(x_j)\in P$.

Comment: The solution remains valid only with the inclusion (and then equality) between $u_i^{-1}(P)$ and $u_i^{-1}(Q)$ without knowing that they are $P\cap R_i$ and $Q\cap R_i$. But, I am not yet convinced that they are. Why $u_i^{-1}(P)$ lies in $P$?

Comment: @karparvar As I already said, by $P\cap R_i$ I understand $u_i^{-1}(P)$. This is a matter of notation, so there is nothing to prove.